# How to resolve this weird behaviour when navigating between two Navigators in React Navigation 6?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

In my code, I have a navigation structure consisting of a Stack and a Bottom Tab. I want to hide the tab on ProfileScreen. Following [React Native Navigation suggestion](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens), I structured the navigation accordingly, But I'm experiencing an issue.

The problem is that when I navigate from `Home -> Profile` and then `Profile -> Feed`, the navigation goes from `Home -> Profile -> Home -> Feed`.

Following is my navigation structure. How can I achieve my requirement without the strange navigation behavior? Or is there any other way to hide the Bottom Tab bar?

This is the [snack.expo](https://snack.expo.dev/yhqS7Iyt8) for reference.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const HomeStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function EmptyScreen() {
    return <View />;
}

function FeedScreen() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

function ProfileScreen({navigation}) {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text>Profile Screen</Text>
            <Button title="Go to Feed" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Feed')} />
        </View>
    );
}

function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            <Button title="Go to Profile" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')} />
        </View>
    );
}

const HomeStackNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <HomeStack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
        </HomeStack.Navigator>
    );
};

function HomeTabs() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackNavigation} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={EmptyScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} options={{headerShown: false}} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a Stack Navigator containing all screens which dont have tab bar and add a Tab Navigator in this stack with all Tab screens.

I have updated your snack with these changes. Please check [here](https://snack.expo.dev/k192L4jUh).

You can also follow [this](https://snack.expo.dev/XLqEEQS9B) example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. But in the FeedScreen I want the tab bar to be visible again.

Comment: Will request you to update the question, in question you have mentioned you want to hide tab bar on FeedScreen.

Comment: It was by mistake. Corrected it. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the snack [here](https://snack.expo.dev/ig3Xc2Wbz), I have added feed screen in tab nav and profile screen in stack nav. Would appreciate if you mark this as correct answer

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstood this. I want only Home and Settings in the HomeTabs. After navigating to Feed I want the Home to be active as Feed is inside Home Stack. Did you get it? I'm more than happy to mark the answer as correct if you add the correct answer. Thanks :)

Comment: hope [this](https://snack.expo.dev/2dLzbPWDJ) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254068/discussion-between-rohit-s-k-and-tharwi).